# Doctrine: Hydrate models from raw SQL

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine-dbal

I have the following custom query. I know its a simple one, so it can also be used as a DQL, but I have more complex ones too. But I want to know the way, how to do it even with more complex queries.

```
select j.*
from `shop`.`jobs` j
-- 2 joins
where j.`active` = true 
order by j.`priority` desc, j.`created` asc
```

Sure have a `Job` model.

**What I want:**

An array of instances from the class Job, using the a raw sql. Like this:

```
array (6) {
    [0] => Job#12 (8) {
      ...
    }
    [1] => Job#13 (8) {
      ...
    }
    [2] => Job#14 (8) {
      ...
    }
    [3] => Job#16 (8) {
      ...
    }
    [4] => Job#17 (8) {
      ...
    }
    [5] => Job#18 (8( {
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking us here! Maybe is you showed us what this produces and then say what you actually want produced

Comment: to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I wrote down what I want, buuut then I make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it! Through the EntityManager's createNativeQuery function. And for the RSM I need to use the ResultSetMappingBuilder class.

```
$rsm = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMappingBuilder($this->getEntityManager());
$rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata(\Path\To\Model::class, 'alias');

$nativeQuery = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery('-- query--', $rsm);

$nativeQuery->getResult();
```